# What is the meaning of this whole sentence?

Tags: meaning

> 'Boots squealing above the whine of the truck.'

It's from a short story. The name is 'The silence', it's by Murray Bail. I checked the words but I couldn't understand. This is the whole paragraph:

> 'Up stood Joe. Boots squealing above the whine of the truck. He climbed on a petrol drum. To the right the truck was making a dust storm against the sky.'

Comment: Can you give us the source of the sentence?  That is technically not a complete sentence, because it does not have a subject and a verb correctly conjugated for the subject, but it might be a sentence fragment used in a literary context.

Comment: It's from a short story. The name is The silence.

Comment: I added a link yto the source. It's mistranscribed, but there's not much difference between ***squeak*** and ***squeal*** in this context anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Boot", singular?

Comment: If I was reading that short story, I think my "willing suspension of disbelief" would have a hard time buying into the idea that Joe's boots are so squeaky they make more noise than a truck engine!

Comment: It's hard to imagine that boots squeal or squeak. Sometimes, writers' editors don't catch stuff like this. Now, if it had said "scraping the floor", that would be dfferent.

Comment: It's not actually a valid sentence.  The writing is terrible. Sorry.

Comment: @Lambie - [Squeaking shoes](https://zensoundproof.com/how-to-stop-shoes-from-squeaking/) is a well-known phenomenon - it used to be jokingly said that stolen shoes squeaked! But it does seem unlikely that it would be louder than the sound of the truck.

Comment: @Lambie - my Doctor Marten shoes and boots sometimes squeak. Flexing of the leather, I think.

Comment: @KateBunting -  My Bristolian colleagues used to say 'it means you're going to come into some money'.

Comment: @Joachim - perhaps if the squeaking was from the single boot of a lone one-legged man.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mentioned it because I found the quote/text somewhere, which said "boot", not because of my idea of internal (in)consistency :)

Comment: My 'Vans' trainer-type shoes squeak in humid weather.

Comment: I repeat: it is hard to imagine **here** that boots squeal or squeak over the sound of the truck. Here's a sound video of supposedly squeaky shoes but it sounds way too **loud** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmD3FHS2n5U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truck is making a sound that is quite high-pitched, and described as a whine (it has roughly the pitch of a human voice). But the boots are making a very high pitched sound, described as a "squeak".  You can hear the boots even though the truck is noisy, probably because the sound the boots make is high pitched

If you hear A over B, it means that A can be heard even though B is noisy.

What we can't tell from this fragment is why the boots are squeaking, or why the truck is whining.  It may be that the boots are new and the leather is rubbing, which makes a high-pitched sound. It may be that the trunk is at high "revs" which makes a "whine". The truck may be far away, which is why it is not too noisy.